# how can I add a new column which counts the number of transactions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched for this answer but couldn't find anything. Hoping for a little help.

| **Transaction_ID** | **User_ID** | **Transaction_Date** | **Amount** | **DayOfTheWeek** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Transaction_01 | User_01 | 2021-09-06 | 532 | Monday |
| Transaction_02 | User_02 | 2021-09-05 | 631 | Sunday |
| Transaction_03 | User_03 | 2021-09-06 | 7214 | Monday |
| Transaction_04 | User_04 | 2021-09-08 | 131 | Wednesday |
| Transaction_05 | User_01 | 2021-09-08 | 13 | Wednesday |
| Transaction_06 | User_03 | 2021-09-09 | 72 | Thursday |
| Transaction_07 | User_05 | 2021-09-11 | 139 | Saturday |
| Transaction_08 | User_05 | 2021-09-13 | 214 | Monday |

Query Needed: I want to add new column called transaction order
that would count no of occurrence , for example
i want column like this

| **Transaction_ID** | **User_ID** | **Transaction_Date** | **Amount** | **DayOfTheWeek** | **TransactionOrder** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Transaction_01 | User_01 | 2021-09-06 | 532 | Monday | First |
| Transaction_02 | User_02 | 2021-09-05 | 631 | Sunday | First |
| Transaction_03 | User_03 | 2021-09-06 | 7214 | Monday | First |
| Transaction_04 | User_04 | 2021-09-08 | 131 | Wednesday | First |
| Transaction_05 | User_01 | 2021-09-08 | 13 | Wednesday | Second |
| Transaction_06 | User_03 | 2021-09-09 | 72 | Thursday | Second |
| Transaction_07 | User_05 | 2021-09-11 | 139 | Saturday | First |
| Transaction_08 | User_05 | 2021-09-13 | 214 | Monday | Second |

Comment: You can use this `ALTER TABLE tbl_name
ADD TransactionOrder varchar(50);`

Comment: But how to write a query that would count accordance.

Comment: ```CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY dow_number) WHEN 1 THEN 'First' WHEN ...```

Comment: HI @akina can you please write a full query

Comment: SO is not query creation service. Create it by yourself, we'd only help you to solve.

Comment: Is the DayOfTheWeek confined  to one week only? i.e No recuring day. Aslo, is there an id column which marks the sequence of all rows ? Without it, how do we guarantee the data appearing in the order displayed in you first table ? Usually, the DayOfTheWeek follows either Monday to Sunday  or Sunday to Saturday order. If so, how come we have Saturday as the first and Monday as the Second for user_05 ?

Comment: Now i Just Updated full Table , Can you Please go through this and Help Me

Answer (score 0):

@Akina has already given you the hint. The only difference is you need to order by Transaction date, not by DayOftheWeek:

```
SELECT *,
(CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Transaction_Date)
WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Fourth'
END) AS TransactionOrder
FROM Transactions;
```

If you test it, It returns:

[image: GHF]